# How to auto number rows if adjacent cell is not blank using VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to auto number rows if adjacent cell is not blank using VBA.
any one from below codes works perfectly , except if it counter blank cells.
as always, your support is much appreciated.
this the expected output
[image]

```
Sub Fill_Serial_Numbers_Option1()
  Dim LastRow As Long
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  If LastRow > 2 Then
     Range("A3:A" & Application.Max(2, LastRow)) = Evaluate("ROW(A1:A" & LastRow & ")")
  End If
End Sub

Sub Fill_Serial_Numbers_Option2()
  Dim LastRow As Long
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  If LastRow > 2 Then
  With Range("A3:A" & LastRow)
    .Cells(1, 1).value = 1
    .DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1, Trend:=False
  End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub testCountNonBlanks()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrA, count As Long, i As Long
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row: count = 1
   If lastR <= 2 Then Exit Sub
   arr = sh.Range("B2:B" & lastR).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
   arrA = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).value
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) <> "" Then arrA(i, 1) = count: count = count + 1
   Next i
   sh.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrA), 1).value = arrA
End Sub
```

If a formula (written in VBA) is allowed, you can use the next variant:

```
Sub testCountByFormula()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngB As Range
  
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   Set rngB = sh.Range("B2:B" & lastR)
   sh.Range("A2:A10").Formula = "=IF(B2<>"""",COUNTA(" & rngB.Address & ")-COUNTA(" & rngB.Address(0, 1) & ")+1,"""")"
End Sub
```

Comment: the first variant Works perfectly and faster, But the other not ( it insert formulas on cells even blank ones ).Great thanks for your support @FaneDuru

Comment: @Waleed78 Glad I could help! But did you try the formula code **exactly as it is**? If the answer is yes, are the values in B:B the result of a formula? If yes, what does the formula return when its evaluation returns `False`?

Comment: @FaneDuru.I tried second variant exactly as it is , no output from formulas ( Just Formulas) and cells format is General https://easyupload.io/5ffayj

Comment: @Waleed78 This only means that the A:A column is formatted **as Text**... If you previously format it as General, it will work. Manually, or in code... It is strange, anyhow... It should increment the value of the B2 in the second part of the formula. Probably, because of the format, too.

Comment: @Waleed78 So, you did not test the code **As it is**... :)

Comment: @FaneDuru.This link for the real sheet to test,  https://easyupload.io/y7f5z9

Comment: on second variant , it assume header is one Row but in my case herder is `two Rows` with merged cells , I fixed the second code by changing B2 to **B3** and replaced sh.Range("A2:A10").Formula = with **sh.Range("A3:A10").Formula =** .now it works correctly.this is just FYI

Comment: @Waleed78 Yes, I did/could not observe the merged cells. I thought that they are only colored the same. And `sh.Range("A3:A10").Formula` should be `sh.Range("A3:A" & lastR).Formula`, in fact...

Comment: Great thanks, Please, is the first variant need also modification or not ?

Comment: @Waleed78 No, there I used the last row in the column. For the second code I prepared a sub, tested on a small range in my computer ("A2:A10") and I forgot adapting it to by dynamic...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a macro to accomplish this. Assuming all you care about is blank or not, then you can use a formula like this in cell `A9`. `=Counta($B$1:$B9)` If you have formulas you can try to leverage something with COuntif.

Comment: @pgSystemTester.I know formula, But for some reasons I need no formulas on coulma A .

Comment: Well then use FaneDuru's answer. Creating an array is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop from the first row to the last one, something like this:

```
Sub Fill()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim Row As Integer
    
    Count = 0
    Row = 1
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    Do While Row <= LastRow
        If Not (Cells(Row, 2) = "") Then
            Count = Count + 1
            Cells(Row, 1) = Count
        End If
        Row = Row + 1
        
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: your code start fill from header rows (A1& A2 are merged in one cell) , so the result is not correct @ Adrian Fischer

Comment: I changed **Row=1** to Row=2 and now works fine.

Comment: Yep, right. When I tested it I didn't have a header.